# How to test 'pull' and 'half pull' actions on mobile browsers with touch screen

Tags: java, webdriver, touch

I am testing a website for touch devices. One of the pages has 'pull to refresh' and 'half pull' for showing search textbox. It is similar to the mail app which comes on iOS devices.

How can I test this functionality using Webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

   Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
       .moveToElement(otherElement)
       .release(otherElement)
       .build();

   dragAndDrop.perform();
```

[documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)

Comment: I haven't tried it but this seems close to what I need. Thanks for linking the documentation.